# Magento in admin panel when click on edit custome it blank can't work?

Tags: magento, admin, edit

My Magento Version is 1.5.1.0-rc1.

When Click on Customer Tab and Manage customer then it will show customer detail proper but when click in edit then give me header and footer without body middle content. Pls help me and give me suggestion what's problem..

Please view attachment ans01.jpg and ans02.jpg.
ans01.jpg is list of customer detail and ans02.jpg is edit page.

Comment: Have you written a custom module?
Have you installed any modules?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your customer.xml in  app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml and check if  the below xml tag are there. If not please check any file will override this cutomer edit action?

```
  <adminhtml_customer_edit>


 </adminhtml_customer_edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

write below code in index.php file and save it to display error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 1);
```

Then write down error what is the exact error in your magento.

For more detail please check this link:

http://bitly.com/hhtaEG

Enjoy !!!!!!!!!1

Comment: Thanks Problem has been solve. Problem is at installation time magento skip file or not proper install customer.xml in 
adminhtml/layout that's prob.

Thanks you for reply